# Handling and Implementing Transactions(Credit/Debit) in a Relational DB

Tags: database-design, transactions, entity-relationship, audit, accounts

This could feels like a duplicate post in the stackoverflow community. But I really want to validate my idea on Transactions(Credit/Debit) which i planed to implementing inside an **Accounting Application**

I searched over the community and i found several of threads related to this topic.But non of the comments in those threads explained about **"What's going to happen if that approach implemented."**

So I'm expecting from community for the thoughts that against my idea. *And also suggestions*, so that i could improve my design.
 
**So this is my application domain:**
I found out that my client(An Auditing company) deals with **at most(a rough round number) 7.2 million** transactions per year. it includes several number of audit data from various companies.
So handling such amount of data could effect performance of the applications when the data amount reaches a higher number.
My approach for storing transactions data inside the DB is like this:

> Storing Transactions and Account as a separate entities.
>   **Account** >: accid(PK)| accname | openningbalance | currentamount | comp_id(FK)
>   **Transaction** >: trid(pk) | tridentifier(UUID) | tr_amount | tr_state
>   There is a **Many-to-Many** relationship.

I'm considering Credit and Debit as separate roles each transaction and account has many Credit and many Debit roles.

> **Account** 1:M **Credit** M:1 **Transaction**
>   **Account** 1:M **Debit** M:1 **Transaction**

When I want to register a transaction: 
register a transactions in transaction table
insert credit considering credit way and reflect the debit way ensuring the balance in the total amount.
**Balancing** will be implemented in the business logic layer

When i want to retrieve data for a particular account :
**accid > seach through Credit Union accid seach through Debit**
Please consider that I'm new in this account application domain. So help me on this design.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this sort of thing is a bit simpler.  Keep in mind that that this separates presentation and storage a little bit.

Usually I have stored amounts in their sign values in relation to equity accounts, i.e. positive for credits and negative for debits.

There are a few advantages to this approach.  The first thing is that if you do sum(amount) over a criteria you can see whether it is debit, credit, or neutral.

So

```
  select transactionid, sum(amount) from transaction_amounts
group by transactionid
  having sum(amount) <> 0
```

gives you a list of unbalanced transactions.